# How bad would be to instance all the fragments of a ViewPager only once?

Tags: android

I use a ViewPager with a small and fixed number of views (just 3 or 4) in my MainActivity. If I follow the traditional way of implementing that ViewPager, I must do:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new MyFragment0();
        case 1:
            return new MyFragment1();
        case 2:
            return new MyFragment2();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this approach, usually only the first and second fragments are instantiated, and, once the user swipes to the second or third tab, the third fragment is instantiated and maybe the first one is destroyed. The advantage is clear: Android only keeps in memory fragments that the user is directly interacting with. In most of my apps I do this and everything is OK, but nowadays I am developing an app that needs these fragments to interact with each other. For example, when a user clicks on a button on the third fragment, some function must be triggered on the first one. When same data is typed in the second fragment, another function must be executed on the third one and so on... My problem is that all the fragments are not instantiated all the time, so it's really painful the need to check if they are or not, and assuring the proper functions will be called once the involved fragments are instantiated (when the user swipes to them).

My question is: how bad would be to instantiate the three (on four) fragments only once and keep all of them on memory, so I can assure they are all instantiated all the time:

```
MyFragment0 myFragment0 = new MyFragment0();
MyFragment1 myFragment1 = new MyFragment1();
MyFragment2 myFragment2 = new MyFragment2();

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return myFragment0;
        case 1:
            return myFragment1;
        case 2:
            return myFragment2;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon the complexity of your Fragments, it's not bad at all, however I'd implement it using the native Offset of the ViewPager:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

This causes the ViewPager to *set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.* So it will keep them in memory.

Experiment and see if it works. In any case, it's not bad to keep your fragments in memory, just make sure you're not reinstaciating them all the time unless it's needed.

Monitor your memory usage, and keep that under control are you're good to go.

Of course, if you instantiate a 20mb bitmap on each fragment… you're going to OOM the App.

On the other hand, design your app so that your Fragments *might* be destroyed. It can happen, and it's not under your total control. (Unless you leak memory). In the end, let Android do its job. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I had no idea of that property. Let's wait a bit and check if anyone has something more to say...